# How can I reformat the output of a RFC5424 log tail to be easier to read?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, logging, rfc

The RFC5424 format of logging messages makes sense, but is hard to read on the fly.

Any ideas on techniques for how to make this easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JSON module to decode it into a native Perl structure, and view it with `Data::Dumper`

```
perl -MJSON -MData::Dumper -0 -ne 'print Dumper decode_json($_)' path/to/log/file
```

Optionally, set the Dumper indent to 1 for better viewing: `$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1`

Answer (score 1):

[logfmt](https://brandur.org/logfmt)

There is no CPAN module for that, but you can approximate it with code like:

```
journalctl -o json | perl -MJSON -lne'
    my $j = decode_json $_;
    my $out = "";
    for my $k (sort keys %$j) {
        my $v = $j->{$k};
        $v = qq("$v") if $v =~ /\s/;
        $out .= "$k=$v ";
    };
    print $out;
'
```

Consume with [colout](https://nojhan.github.io/colout/) or [lnav](http://lnav.org/) for greater usability.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to put this somewhere in case someone finds a use for it one day.

Working in adonis.js, I found the Logger class very useful, but its output hard to read on the fly.

I did some digging and couldn't find a reasonable solution so I did some legwork to get to this result:

```
tail path/to/log/file -f | perl -pe 's/^.*?"level":"([^"]*)".*?"message":"((\\"|[^"])*)".*?"timestamp":"([^"]*)".*?$/\e[0;36m|\e[0m\e[1;30m $1: $4\n\r\e[0m\e[0;36m|\e[0m $2\n\r/'
```

This will turn a typical log of an RFC5424 formatted log file entry of this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Hope this is useful to someone!